# Windows Phone 8.1 Media Element set position from totalmilliseconds

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, mediaelement

I am trying to set position of my Media Element pragmatically but position is always setting to 0:0:0 Whose autoPlay property I disable when I

```
Media_Final_Outside.Stop();//Stoping earlier set source
    Media_Final_Outside.AutoPlay = false;
        Media_Final_Outside.SetSource(streamDeAcceleration_Outside2, fileDeAcceleration_Outside2.ContentType);

Media_Final_Outside.Position = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,((int)(Math.Ceiling(temp))));
```

Neither

```
Media_Final_Outside.Position = new TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(temp);
```

is setting the position. Also If I type
`Media_Final_Outside.Play();` still it wont play even if position was on zero.
How Can I set the source of my AutoPlay media using C# and play it starting from a position other than 0:0:0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to solve the same problem with Media Element on Windows 8.1 so it should work the same way for you on the phone.

Subscribe to the Opened event and set the position when it is fired.

Comment: Well that was my plan but subscribing to opened event would result in it setting the default position of my player to that position for all sounds wont it?
 Media_Final_Outside.SetSource(streamDeAcceleration_Outside2, fileDeAcceleration_Outside2.ContentType);

                Media_Final_Outside.MediaOpened += (s, args) =>
 {
     var player = (MediaElement)s;
     if (player.CanSeek)
         player.Position = temp.Position;
 };

Comment: Then I will have to replace all my Media.Setsource with an Opened event Why is mediaElement so buggy. Tried using XAudio2 but it doesnt provide seek option.

Comment: Could you help me as to how did you remove the opened event as now all my songs are using the new opened event. and every song position is setting to the new position

Comment: assign the TimeSpan to a variable and then make it null when you set the position